# Нужно добавить кнопку на сайт через js

Tags: javascript, html

Как добавить кнопку которая будет автоматически отправлять текст?

```html
<div class="editorPlaceholder-editor">
<div class="fr-box bbWrapper fr-ltr fr-basic fr-top" role="application">
    <div style="max-height: 685px; overflow: auto;" class="fr-wrapper show-placeholder" dir="ltr">
        <div class="fr-element fr-view" dir="ltr" contenteditable="true" aria-disabled="false" style="min-height: 63px;" spellcheck="true">
            <p><br></p>
        </div>
        <span class="fr-placeholder" style="font-size: 13px; line-height: 18.2px; margin-top: 0px; padding-top: 16px; padding-left: 16px; margin-left: 0px; padding-right: 16px; margin-right: 0px; text-align: left;">Напишите что-нибудь...</span>
    </div>
</div>
<textarea name="message_html" class="input js-editor u-jsOnly" data-xf-init="editor" data-original-name="message" data-buttons-remove="" style="height: 77px; display: none;" aria-label="Текстовое поле с поддержкой форматирования" data-min-height="40" placeholder="Напишите что-нибудь..." data-deferred="on" data-xf-key="r"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" value="" data-bb-code="message">
<div class="formButtonGroup formButtonGroup--simple">
    <div class="formButtonGroup-primary">
        <button type="submit" class="button--primary button button--icon button--icon--reply">
            <span class="button-text">Отправить</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="last_date" value="1608116571" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="last_known_date" value="1608116571" autocomplete="off">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: что в вашем понимании означает фраза "кнопка автоматически отправляет текст"?

Comment: чтобы рядом с клавишей отправить была клавиша на подобии "роспись"
и при нажатии на клавишу роспись отправлялся текст который я напишу

Comment: отправляется куда?

Comment: "fr-box bbWrapper fr-ltr fr-basic fr-top

Comment: Лучше отвечайте на русском, так будет понятнее =)

Comment: <div class="fr-element fr-view" dir="ltr" contenteditable="true" aria-disabled="false" style="min-height: 63px;" spellcheck="true"><p><br></p></div>

Comment: блок ввода текста

Answer (score 1):

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
const text = document.querySelector('#text');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => text.innerText = input.value);
```

```css
#btn {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#btn:hover {
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<div id="btn">
  Перепечатать текст!
</div>
<div id="text">
</div>
```